# Fabric: Failed to retrieve settings from crashlytics after moving the apiKey from AndroidManifest to fabric.properties

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric, crashlytics-android

I want to hide my fabric apiKey and follow the guide in https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/settings/working-in-teams.html#android-projects.

After I move the fabric apiKey from AndroidManifest to the `fabric.properties` file, fabric shows `E/Fabric: Failed to retrieve settings from https://settings.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/platforms/android/apps/myapp`
and there is no report to fabric console anymore.

Is there any step I missed? Please help..

Answer (score 0):

you need to download updated google-services.plist and json file from Firebase console project settings after adding crashlytics in the project.

Answer (score -2):

Adding the **meta-data** back in the **AndroidManifest.xml** fixed the issue for me.

```xml
<application>
    <activity
        ...>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="xxxxxx" />
</application>
```

I keep the API key in both places (AndroidManifest.xml and fabric.properties). Hope it works for you as well.